# Why doesn't Apache recognize Passenger configurations in my .htaccess file?

Tags: node.js, apache, .htaccess

I want to start directing traffic through a Node app, rather than simply serving up static files.

I added the following to my website's public_html/.htaccess, according to advice I got from my VPS provider [here](https://help.asmallorange.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/286/1/getting-started-with-nodejs-on-a-small-orange):

```
PassengerEnabled on
PassengerAppRoot /home/user/myapp
SetEnv NODE_ENV production
SetEnv NODE_PATH /usr/lib/node_modules
```

But the browser is throwing internal server errors. The `error-log` says the following:

```
[Mon Oct 13 21:11:07 2014] [alert] [client 54.176.38.134] /home/devbryce/public_html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'PassengerAppRoot', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

[Mon Oct 13 21:16:57 2014] [alert] [client 54.237.229.212] /home/devbryce/public_html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'PassengerEnabled', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

It seems like something related to Passenger has not been properly imported. But I'm not sure what that is or how I would import it.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're VPS provider hasn't installed the passenger module for apache.